# Equivalent object 'table' of R in C#

Tags: c#, r, frequency

I want to use `table` function from R in C# for following purpose:

```
> tmp <- table(c("c1","c1", "c1", "c2", "c2")[c(1,2,3,4,5)])

> tmp

c1 c2 
 3  2
```

If I edit further code like below it should reproduce the output as

```
> tmp <- table(c("c1","c1", "c1", "c2", "c2")[c(1,2,3)])
> tmp

c1 
 3
```

Does anyone know how to do this in c#? I Further want to use tmp to compare with the string containing c1 and c2.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Resembles `Dictionary<String, int>`; however, to mimic R behavior you have to implement some (extension) methods

Comment: @Dmitry, Thank you for your reply. What extension methods do I need to implement?

Comment: so you have to describe what `table` function does (and what you expect from its C# emulation): something like *given two arrays (String an Integer) of same size the emulation should return iDictionary<String, int> where key is unique value from the frist array and value is...*